# How to send notifications using FCM after every new entry in Firebase Real-time database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a group messaging app that makes use of Firebase-Real time database. I am trying devise a way that whenever a user sends a message all the group members receive notification of message.

Following is the structure of my database.

```
plan-129a0
    |
    -- plan
         |
         -- LVAMCUC8S0S6tuTtLjk
            |
            -- exp_duration: "same_day"
            |
            -- members
                |
                -- 0: member_id
                |
                -- 1: member_id
            |
            -- messages
                |
                -- LVAMDqIHDrTDeTUrfkM
                |
                -- msgTime: 
                |
                -- name:
                |
                -- text: "Hello World"
            |
            -- name: "Plan one"
            |
            -- plan_admin: 
            |
            -- timeCreated: "Wed"

    user
      |
      -- LT46t95CKQ9dFgXv-JF
            |
            -- name:
            |
            -- number:
            |
            -- uid:
```

I am trying to send a notification every time there is a new entry in the messages node to every user that is in the members node. My question is that can Firebase Cloud Functions achieve this task?

Some of posts that I have gone through on how to implement this state that I need a token for every device in order send them notification. What is this token and how do I get this in Android for every device that registers with my app?

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you want to send messages to all members of a group. This means you must somehow know what devices the members of the group are using the app on. Each device that the app is installed on is identified by a so-called App Instance ID (also often referred to as an FCM token), so you essentially need to map these tokens/IDs to your application's groups.

You have two options for doing this with FCM:

1. Use a topic to identify each group

   This means that the app should [subscribe to the topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic) for each group that the user is a member of. And then to send a message to the group, you call the FCM API to [send a message to that group's topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_topics).

   In this option, FCM manages the relationship between the groups and tokens for you, and it handles the expansion of the group to the list of tokens.
2. Keep track of what app instances related to each group

   This means that you need to [get the App Instance IDs/FCM tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) for each user and store them in your own database, keeping in mind that there may be multiple, and that they may expire. Then when you want to send a message to a group, you look up all IDs/tokens for that group, and call the FCM API to [send a message to a list of tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_multiple_devices).

   In this option, you are managing the relationship between groups and tokens yourself. This allows you more flexibility, but also means you have to do more work in managing the data.